# Selector does not work in the component html

Tags: javascript, html, angular

In the project below, I try to respect best practice when use the Oriented Object Programming approach. I saw that nothing is appear on my page; then I'd like to know if is it always a good idea to use private property parameter in the constructor in a angular project? According to the files below, the selector <app-student> does not show the template.

**person.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';


type Gender = "Male" | "Female";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person',
  templateUrl: './person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person.component.css']
})
export class PersonComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(String) private _firstName: string,
    @Inject(String) private _lastName: string,
    @Inject(String) private _adresse: string,
    @Inject(String) private _gender: Gender,
    @Inject(String) private _id: string = ""
    ){
        if(!_id || _id === "") this._id = this.createId(this._firstName,this._lastName)
    }

get id(): string{
    return this._id;
}

set id(value: string){
  this._id = value
};

set firstName(value: string){
  this._id = value;
}
get firstName(): string{
    return this._firstName;
}

set lastName(value: string){
  this._lastName = value;
}

get lastName(): string{
    return this._lastName;
}

set gender(value: Gender){
  this._gender= value;
}

get gender(): Gender{
    return this._gender;
}

set adresse(value: string){
  this._adresse= value;
}

get adresse(): string{
    return this._adresse;
}



private createId(firstNameGiven: string, lastNameGiven: string): string{
    if (firstNameGiven.length > 4 && lastNameGiven.length > 3){
        let lefttPart: string = firstNameGiven.substring(0,3);
        let rigthPart: string = lastNameGiven.slice(0,3)

        let randomId = function(max: number){
            Math.random() * max;
        }
        return randomId(10) + lefttPart + randomId(5) + rigthPart;
    }
    throw new Error("It's impossible to create the Id");
  }


}
```

**student.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-student',
  templateUrl: './student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student.component.css']
})
export class StudentComponent extends PersonComponent implements OnInit {
  maListe = [];
  title = "Signup form";
  /**
   *
   */
  constructor(
      @Inject(String) private _classe: string,
      @Inject(String) firstName: string,
      @Inject(String) lastName: string,
      @Inject(String) adresse: string,
      @Inject(String) gender: Gender
    ) {
    super(firstName, lastName, adresse, gender);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }


  set classe(value: string){
    this._classe = value;
  }

  get classe(): string{
      return this._classe;
  }


  addStudent(){
    this.maListe.push({
      id: this.id,
      prenom: this.firstName,
      nom: this.lastName,
      adresse: this.adresse,
      genre: this.gender,
      classe: this.classe
    });
  }

}
```

**student.component.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Student - page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div><h3>{{ title }}</h3><hr></div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Prénom" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="lastName"><br>
    <input type="text" id="nom" placeholder="Nom" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="firstName"><br>
    <input type="text" id="adresse" placeholder="Adresse" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="adresse"><br>
    <select name="" id="genre" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="gender"><br>
        <option value="Masculin">male</option>
        <option value="Féminin">female</option>
    </select><br>
    <select name="" id="classe" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="classe">
        <option value="Préparatoire 1">Classe one</option>
    </select> <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" (click)="inscrireEleve()">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Cancel</button>
</div>

<div class="div" *ngFor="let elem of maListe">
    {{elem | json}}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2" id="div_left">
            <!-- Inscrire un(e) elève -->
            <app-student>

            </app-student>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: These component are not `standAlone`, hence they needs to be part of  `declarations` array in `app.module.ts`. Are they ?

Comment: yes, they are in the app.module.ts.

Comment: I believe the issue might be the way you inherit the component. You can check this for more info: https://nartc.me/blog/inheritance-angular-inject/

Comment: Thank you for the link @CanGeylan. It's difficult to understand and to adapt according to my code.